# How to detect field name typo when saving a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a typo in a Mongoose Schema and the field in the POST request did not match that in the database. So Mongoose did not save that field in the document.

The form had this field (in PUG):

```
input(type="checkbox" id="happiness", name="happiness", value="true")
label(for="happiness") feels happier
```

The Mongoose Schema was missing an `s` in that field:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Use native promises.
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Define the schema.
const QuestionnaireSchema = new Schema({

  happines: Boolean,
  // ...
}
```

So the field `happiness` in `req.body` was discarded without a warning.

How can I ensure that every field in the `req.body` object be present in the Mongoose schema?

Comment: set `required` to `true` for all the fields in the mongoose schema?

Comment: Setting `required` for checkbox inputs would require users to mark the checkbox, but this is an optional field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `strict` option. `strict` option is by default enabled and this will drop fields that are not present in schema, but you can set its value to `throw` which will cause errors to be produced.

```js
const QuestionnaireSchema = new Schema({}, {strict: 'throw'})
```